# Hyperledger Fabric Test Network: $ sudo ./network.sh up (not working)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am new to hyperledger fabric and stuck in a error when setting up the test-network. 
I downloaded fabric-samples from docker-compose github repository.
Then changed directory to test-network. 
Now when i am running the command $ `sudo ./network.sh up`, i am getting the error shown in the image link.
[Error from $ sudo ./network.sh up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDexK.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Comment: I haven't tried docker compose, but if you have Kubernetes you could refer running the Fabric: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network-k8s

Answer (score 0):

Before you can run the fabric-sample test network you need to setup certain prerequisites. just downloading the  from docker-compose github repository is not the documented approach on :

you need to

1. Install the Prerequisites -
   https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/prereqs.html
2. Download Hyperledger Fabric Samples, Binaries, and Docker Images  - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/install.html
3. Setup /  start the Network - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/test_network.html

Kindly follow the install guide provided above to set up the test network.

Comment: i did what what was suggested by you and installed the prerequisites.
now i am getting version compatibility issue for docker-compose.
pip is installing docker-compose v1.
i updated to docker-compose v2 and getting the error mentioned in my post.
i am trapped in this cycle where both the docker-compose versions are giving me errors.